# Filtering grouped results on COUNT of a number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I basically have a very simple query like such

```
SELECT accounts . * , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
GROUP BY followings.receive
ORDER BY COUNT(receive) DESC
```

I've tried changing it to the following and it's failing

```
SELECT accounts . * , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
    AND total_accounts < 10
GROUP BY followings.receive
ORDER BY COUNT(receive) DESC
```

`Unknown column 'total_counts' in 'where clause'`

I'm sorry for posting such simple question, but my mind is boggling right now

Comment: In the second query, you use `total_counts` as the column alias, but `total_accounts` in the WHERE clause. Is it possible that mismatch is what's causing the problem?

Comment: What makes you think `total_accounts` is a thing?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause only operates on actual table columns. Calculated columns can be addressed in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: **remove the space between the table and the `*`**: `accounts.*`.

Second: You cannot use `where` on aggregate expressions. You need to use `having`:

```
SELECT accounts.* , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
GROUP BY followings.receive
HAVING total_accounts < 10
ORDER BY COUNT(receive) DESC
```

A little guide on how does the select works:

```
SELECT "Fields and expressions"
FROM "Tables, views and / or subqueries"
WHERE "Conditions to apply on the raw data (contained directly in the FROM clause)"
GROUP BY "Grouping fields"
HAVING "Conditions to apply on the grouped data or (aggregate) expressions"
```

Comment: The spaces actually shouldn't matter - SQL is supposed to handle that fine.

Answer (score 2):

To filter *before* a `GROUP BY` clause, use `WHERE`, to filter *afterwards*, use `HAVING`. Since the aggregation of the `count` occurs during the grouping, it gives an error in the `WHERE` clause - it's simply not known yet at that point of execution. Change to:

```
SELECT accounts.* , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
GROUP BY followings.receive
HAVING count(receive) < 10
ORDER BY COUNT(receive) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT accounts.* , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
GROUP BY followings.receive  --<-- You need to GROUP BY All the columns
                                 -- In your select that are not containted 
                               -- in any Aggregate Function i.e accounts.*


ORDER BY total_counts DESC  --<-- ORDER BY you need to use the Alias
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT accounts.* , COUNT(receive) as total_counts
FROM followings
LEFT JOIN accounts ON followings.receive = accounts.account_id
WHERE accounts.status <1
  --  AND total_accounts < 10 --<-- Where Clause Filters the Rows
                                -- Before doing any aggregates you
                                -- need to use HAVING Clause when checking
                                -- against aggregated values

GROUP BY followings.receive   --<-- You need to GROUP BY All the columns
                                 -- In your select that are not containted 
                               -- in any Aggregate Function i.e accounts.*
HAVING total_accounts < 10
ORDER BY total_counts DESC --<-- ORDER BY you need to use the Alias
```

Comment: In MySQL you don't need to list all the columns in the `group by` clause (it is desirable but not required): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @Barranka I didnt see the mysql tag on question until just now when you mentioned :)